# Consume WCF service in windows application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, window

I have created WCF service in project. Now using Jquery I am successfully able to consume service, but when I tried to add service as web reference in windows application, I am unable to invoke it. If I create simple service, I can successfully invoke in windows application, but if I do changes to invoke service for jquery, which I found by doing some Google search. I don't know where I am missing.

Below is the code, I have done.
This is the interface for WCF.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]    
    string HelloWorld();
}
```

Class invoking Interface

```
    public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }


    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

}

and here is the web config for the application.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="TestWCFBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TestWCFBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
  <services>
    <service name="WebAppWithWCF.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="TestWCFBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebAppWithWCF.ITestService" behaviorConfiguration="TestWCFBehavior"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have done some try and error, but couldn't found a way till now...

Please help... and let me know if any information is missing from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webHttpBinding does not expose metadata and thus you cannot add a reference to it.

Basically, the *Add Service Reference* feature generates proxies and classes based on what is known of the service (exposed via *metadata* / [WDSL](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)).

Services with wsHttpBinding or basicHttpBinding both expose your service's metadata. They are usually used when you're building a .NET to .NET client-server application.

Implementing both binding: [WCF Service with webHttpBinding-basicHttpBinding-wcHttpBinding](http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com/2010/06/wcf-service-with-webhttpbinding.html)

Comment: We can add multiple binding, and that is quite handy when we like to expose to multiple things. Thanks Max.